# I wanted to read the values in command line using java but i couldn't do it

Tags: java

here is my program

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
  Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   System.out.println("Enter the INTEGER");
int num = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter the double");
double d=in.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the String");
String s=" ";
        s=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String:" + s);
        System.out.println("Double:"+d);
        System.out.println("Int:"+num);
    }
```

}

Output

Enter the INTEGER
1
Enter the double
1.1
Enter the String
String:
Double:1.1
Int:1

I should display string value but i unable to do please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Put extra `nextLine` before you read the string like below :

```
in.nextLine();
s=in.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String s = in.next();
```